# Call to undefined function that isn't undefined?

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, shopify

So, when I try and run this line of code, I'm getting the following error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_http_api_request_() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/CI/application/libraries/Shopify.php on line 58

Where line 58 is specifically this line:

```
$response = curl_http_api_request_($method, $url, $query, $payload, $request_headers, $response_headers);
```

I'm not really sure why it can't call the second function. The code is below. I've got no clue and am at a loss as to what the issue is.

```
class Shopify
{
public $_api_key;
public $_shared_secret;
public $CI; // To hold the CI superglobal



public function __construct ()
{
    $this->_assign_libraries(); // Loads the CI superglobal and loads the config into it

    // Get values from the CI config
    $this->_api_key                     = $this->CI->config->item('api_key', 'shopify');
    $this->_shared_secret               = $this->CI->config->item('shared_secret', 'shopify');
}

public function shopify_app_install_url($shop_domain)
{
    return "http://$shop_domain/admin/api/auth?api_key=". $this->_api_key;
}


public function shopify_is_app_installed($shop, $t, $timestamp, $signature)
{
    return (md5($this->_shared_secret . "shop={$shop}t={$t}timestamp={$timestamp}") === $signature);
}


public function shopify_api_client($shops_myshopify_domain, $shops_token, $private_app=false)
{
    $password = $private_app ? $this->_shared_secret : md5($this->_shared_secret.$shops_token);
    $baseurl = "https://" . $this->_api_key . ":$password@$shops_myshopify_domain/";

    return function ($method, $path, $params=array(), &$response_headers=array()) use ($baseurl)
    {
        $url = $baseurl.ltrim($path, '/');
        $query = in_array($method, array('GET','DELETE')) ? $params : array();
        $payload = in_array($method, array('POST','PUT')) ? stripslashes(json_encode($params)) : array();
        $request_headers = in_array($method, array('POST','PUT')) ? array("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8", 'Expect:') : array();

        $response = curl_http_api_request_($method, $url, $query, $payload, $request_headers, $response_headers);
        $response = json_decode($response, true);

        if (isset($response['errors']) or ($response_headers['http_status_code'] >= 400))
            throw new ShopifyApiException(compact('method', 'path', 'params', 'response_headers', 'response', 'shops_myshopify_domain', 'shops_token'));

        return (is_array($response) and (count($response) > 0)) ? array_shift($response) : $response;
    };
}

    public function curl_http_api_request_($method, $url, $query='', $payload='', $request_headers=array(), &$response_headers=array())
    {
        $url = curl_append_query_($url, $query);
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopts_($ch, $method, $payload, $request_headers);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $errno = curl_errno($ch);
        $error = curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        if ($errno) throw new ShopifyCurlException($error, $errno);

        list($message_headers, $message_body) = preg_split("/\r\n\r\n|\n\n|\r\r/", $response, 2);
        $response_headers = $this->curl_parse_headers_($message_headers);

        return $message_body;
    }

        private function curl_append_query_($url, $query)
        {
            if (empty($query)) return $url;
            if (is_array($query)) return "$url?".http_build_query($query);
            else return "$url?$query";
        }

        private function curl_setopts_($ch, $method, $payload, $request_headers)
        {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 3);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'HAC');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

            if ('GET' == $method)
            {
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
            }
            else
            {
                curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
                if (!empty($request_headers)) curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
                if (!empty($payload))
                {
                    if (is_array($payload)) $payload = http_build_query($payload);
                    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
                }
            }
        }

        private function curl_parse_headers_($message_headers)
        {
            $header_lines = preg_split("/\r\n|\n|\r/", $message_headers);
            $headers = array();
            list(, $headers['http_status_code'], $headers['http_status_message']) = explode(' ', trim(array_shift($header_lines)), 3);
            foreach ($header_lines as $header_line)
            {
                list($name, $value) = explode(':', $header_line, 2);
                $name = strtolower($name);
                $headers[$name] = trim($value);
            }

            return $headers;
        }


public function shopify_calls_made($response_headers)
{
    return shopify_shop_api_call_limit_param_(0, $response_headers);
}

public function shopify_call_limit($response_headers)
{
    return shopify_shop_api_call_limit_param_(1, $response_headers);
}

public function shopify_calls_left($response_headers)
{
    return shopify_call_limit($response_headers) - shopify_calls_made($response_headers);
}

    private function shopify_shop_api_call_limit_param_($index, $response_headers)
    {
        $params = explode('/', $response_headers['http_x_shopify_shop_api_call_limit']);
        return (int) $params[$index];
    }


/**
 * Shopify::_assign_libraries()
 *
 * Grab everything from the CI superobject that we need
 */
 public function _assign_libraries()
 {

        $this->CI =& get_instance();


        $this->CI->load->config('shopify', TRUE);

        return;

 }
```

UPDATE:
This whole line is started off by me calling this line of code:

```
$shopify = $this->shopify->shopify_api_client($shops_myshopify_domain, $shops_token);
```

I have also updated the code above to include the entire file.

Comment: As the method/function is in a class you need to state that eg `$response = $this->curl_http_api_request_(....)`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone: I think you should post that as an answer. :-)

Comment: $this is not good, as it throws this error: Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context. Anonymous function has its own context so you cant use $this inside it...

Comment: Check out my answer below. I tested this code and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it only by passing $this as object to anonymous function, as it has its own context:

```
class example {
    public function trigger() {
        $func = $this->func();
        $func($this);
    }

    public function func() {
        return function($obj) {
            $obj->inner();
        };
    }

    public function inner() {
        die('inside inner');
    }
}

$obj = new example();
$obj->trigger();
```

EDIT: So in response to your problem:

1. Change this line:

   return function ($method, $path, $params=array(), &$response_headers=array()) use ($baseurl)

into this:

```
return function ($instance, $method, $path, $params=array(), &$response_headers=array()) use ($baseurl)
```

1. Inside anonymous function change this line:

   $response = curl_http_api_request_($method, $url, $query, $payload, $request_headers, $response_headers);

into this:

```
$response = $instance->curl_http_api_request_($method, $url, $query, $payload, $request_headers, $response_headers);
```

1. Now shopify_api_client function will return you this ANONYMOUS FUNCTION with no error:

   $shopify = $this->shopify->shopify_api_client($shops_myshopify_domain, $shops_token);
2. You need to call this function in this way:

   $shopify($this->shopify, ... AND HERE THE REST OF ARGUMENTS WHICH ANONYMOUS FUNCTION REQUIRE ...);

Is it clearer now? I have never used shopify, but general way it should work is as I wrote.

Comment: Can you take a look at the code now that I update it? I don't know that I quite understand your answer, and I think the additional code makes it a little clearer what I'm trying to do.

Comment: FYI in PHP5.4 `$this` is available within anonymous functions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php (under changelog)

Comment: @MikeB I am not on PHP5.4, so I do get the error: Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context

Comment: See my EDIT, hope it helps! @MikeB - thanks for this - I didnt know PHP 5.4 did sth about it. Did you try $this works outside function after returning it?

Comment: Ok took me a bit to wrap my head around this all, but I think I get it now! And it seems to be returning the function as you said. Thanks so much for the help. Now to figure out what this new error it's returning means!

Answer (score 2):

If your accessing a method from outside the class you need to state it, if your accessing the method from within the class you need use `$this->methodname()`

```
<?php
class shopify_api{
    ...

    ...

    ...
    public function curl_http_api_request_($method, $url, $query='', $payload='', $request_headers=array(), &$response_headers=array())
    {
        $url = curl_append_query_($url, $query);
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopts_($ch, $method, $payload, $request_headers);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $errno = curl_errno($ch);
        $error = curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        if ($errno) throw new ShopifyCurlException($error, $errno);

        list($message_headers, $message_body) = preg_split("/\r\n\r\n|\n\n|\r\r/", $response, 2);
        $response_headers = $this->curl_parse_headers_($message_headers);

        return $message_body;
    }

}

$shopify = new shopify_api();
//--------V
$response=$shopify->curl_http_api_request_();
?>
```

---

**Since you have updated your question have you tried changing:**

```
$shopify = $this->shopify->shopify_api_client($shops_myshopify_domain, $shops_token);
```

**too:** (as it seems your adding extra shopify property, i cant see from yourcode where you have set & injected your methods to it)

```
$shopify = $this->shopify_api_client($shops_myshopify_domain, $shops_token);
```

Comment: if anyone knows what `$shopify` would be classed as when attaching a class to it let me know, is it still known as a variable? lol its an variable object right lol

Comment: Perhaps I didn't put quite enough information. I'm calling a different function first. I will update the original post.